# Confusion on the proof that a totally associative ring must be unital

Tags: ring-theory, proof-explanation

I was reading a post on mathoverflow about why we sometimes need rngs (or pseudo-rings). A contributor commented on this post an argument ([here](http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/ring.pdf)) that rings need an identity to achieve total associativity (that every possible association of a product is the same). Here is the author's argument:
[image]

But I found this argument confusing: the author is apparently assuming that $a$ is the product of **something** and $a$ ($()\cdot a$, which thus gives that $()$ should be the identity). However, $a$ is not required to be a product; it can be a single element, and still, the equation $a=a$ suffices by the definition of the equivalence relation $=$.

Can somebody explain this argument (or theorem) for me?

Comment: This is a bit of a philosophical point. The idea is that total associativity should include all finite products, including the empty product () of 0 things. The moment you allow the empty product to be an element of your rng, the above gives that the rng must actually be a ring with the empty product  () as your unit.

Comment: @lc2r43 Would you like to migrate your comment to a new answer? It seems fair to consider your comment as an answer.